# Highcharts - How to show two tooltips for single point at different positions of chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to display two different tooltips for same series point. Is there a way we can specify to show one tooltip on the corner using positioner and one just next to the point like default.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the custom tooltip by using simple HTML/CSS and Highcharts point events combination.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qhgpykLd/

HTML:

```
<div id="tooltip">custom tooltip</div>
```

CSS:

```
#tooltip {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    color:'red';
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:80px;
    background: white;
    display:none;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.point.events